# In a circle there are $m$ chords and no $3$ are concurrent, $n$ intersections in the interior. Show there are $m+n+1$ regions dividied by the chords.

Tags: combinatorics

> In a circle there are $m$ chords such that no $3$ are concurrent and
>   there are $n$ intersections of these chords in the interior of the
>   circle. Prove that the number of regions divided by the chords is
>   given by $m+n+1$

For example in the above diagram there are $3$ chords, $3$ points of intersection and $7$ regions.[image]

Tried both counting the regions and establishing some sort of a bijection with a set of $m+n+1$ elements but didnt get very far. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Try to prove the following statements:

- There is one initial region.
- Every chord with no intersection adds *one* region.
- Every chord with $k$ intersections adds $k+1$ regions.
- Each intersection is determined by two chords.

Answer (score 0):

Alteratively you can consider the whole thing as a planar graph where:

- The vertices are the $n$ interior intersections and the $2m$ intersections between the circle and the chords.
- The edges are the segments of chord between two consecutive intersections, the arcs between two consecutive chords and the segments of chord bewteen a chord and the circle (with no intersections in between).

Then you want to use Euler's characteristic to find the number of faces:

$$F + |V| = |E| + 2$$

We can calculate $|E|$ because we know the degree of each vertex:

- There are $2m$ intersections between chords and the circle: these verices have degree $3$.
- There are $n$ interior intersections (between two chords): these verices have degree $4$.

So using:

$$\sum_{v\in V} \deg v = 2|E|$$

So $2|E| = 3\cdot 2m + 4\cdot n \Rightarrow |E| = 3m+2n$.

We also know $|V| = 2m + n$ as stated above.

Therefore:

$$F + 2m + n = 3m + 2n + 2 \Rightarrow F = m + n + 2$$

Note that the regions we want are the ones *inside* the circle, and there is one region outside of it, so the amount of regions is $F-1$:

$m + n + 1$